# Unable to use match(); to check contents of a string in jquery

Tags: jquery, match, traversal

I have a list of links and i'd like jquery to look through those links and find the ones that have a href attribute with values that end with a string ".pdf".

If the value for the src attribute on a particular link ends with ".pdf", i want jquery to insert an image icon (pdf) icon right after that particular link. This helps the user to visually be able to distinguish a regular link vs a pdf file link.

Here's the markup

```
<ul class="navlist" id="navlinks">
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #1</a></li>
    <li><a name="#anchor1">Named Anchor Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #4</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #5</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #7</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:joe@joe.com">Email Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the js i've written

```
var links = $('#navlinks li a');

links.each(function() {
    var hrefVal = $(this).attr("href");
    if (hrefVal.match(/.pdf$/)) {
        //We can now append the icon to this particular link.
    }
});
```

Error i'm getting on the console:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined**

I don't understand why this is happening. I've found another solution to achieve this:

I've found another way to achieve this with lesser lines of code

```
$('#navlinks li a[href$=".pdf"]').after('<img src="images/small_pdf_icon.gif" alt="PDF Icon" title="PDF File download" />');
```

I just need help figuring out why the match method won't work?
Any help is greatly appreciated. **Thanks guys :)**

Answer (score 1):

You have an `a` with no `href` attribute, so `.attr` returns `undefined`.  A better selector would be `"#navlinks li a[href]"`, which selects only those `a` that have an `href` attribute.

Comment: New here, didn't know i could do that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A shorter one liner is as this:

```
$('li a[href$=".pdf"]').after("<img src='small_pdf_icon.gif' align='absbottom' />");
```